# Me sale none cuando imprimo una clase con el código if y else

Tags: python, python-3.x

Cuando imprimo las  clases def saldos, ingresos o retiros, me sale abajito de la impresión la palabra None None. La impresión si me sale bien, pero no me gusta que salga abajito la palabra None y me gustaría saber como hacer para que no salga. Acá dejo el código:

```
class cuentaBancaria:
  def __init__(self, titular, numero_de_cuenta, saldo):
    self.titular = titular
    self.numero_de_cuenta = numero_de_cuenta
    self.saldo = saldo

  def inicio(self):
    inicios = input("¿Que tramite quiere realizar?: ")
    if inicios == "ingreso":
     print(cuentaBancaria.ingresos(self))
    elif inicios == "retirar":
      print(cuentaBancaria.retiros(self))
    elif inicios == "saldo":
      print(cuentaBancaria.saldos(self)) 

  def ingresos(self):
    ingreso = int(input("¿Cuanto quiere ingresar de dinero?: "))
    aumento2 = self.saldo + ingreso
    aumento = (f"Tu saldo es ahora de: {aumento2}")
    return aumento
  
  def retiros(self):
    retiro = int(input("Cuanto dinero quieres retirar?: "))
    if retiro > self.saldo:
      print("Ud no cuenta con el saldo suficiente")
    else:
      disminucion2 = self.saldo - retiro
      disminucion = (f"Tu saldo es ahora de: {disminucion2}")
      return disminucion  
  
  def saldos(self):
    saldo_actual = self.saldo
    return saldo_actual

mi_sueldo = cuentaBancaria("Juan", 199733051214, 0)
print(mi_sueldo.inicio())
```

Ya intente poniendo print() o poniendo saldo_actual(), disminucion() y aumento(), pero me sale igual. Alguien podría ayudarme. Así es como me sale al momento de imprimirlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El primer None es por el print de cuentaBancaria.retiros debido a que esta última no retorna ningún dato cuando el saldo es insuficiente y el segundo None es porque Inicio tampoco retorna  dato dato alguno.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cómo bien te comenta @[Juan Carlos Guibovich](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/152765/juan-carlos-guibovich),
*el **primer** **None** es por el print de **cuentaBancaria.retiros** debido a que esta última no retorna ningún dato cuando el saldo es insuficiente(fíjate que solo retorna cuando sale por el "else", lo tienes tabulado para que solo afecte en el "else") y el **segundo** **None** es porque Inicio tampoco retorna dato alguno(no tienes "return" en esa función, yo lo he incluido y así ya no devuelve "None, devuelve el strin necesario"), es por los retornos de las funciones*.

Por otro lado, tampoco te hacen falta tantos print. Te dejo lo que hice para resolverlo:

```
class cuentaBancaria:
  def __init__(self, titular, numero_de_cuenta, saldo):
    self.titular = titular
    self.numero_de_cuenta = numero_de_cuenta
    self.saldo = saldo

  def inicio(self):
    inicios = input("¿Que tramite quiere realizar?: ")
    if inicios == "ingreso":
     mensaje = cuentaBancaria.ingresos(self)
    elif inicios == "retirar":
      mensaje = cuentaBancaria.retiros(self)
    elif inicios == "saldo":
      mensaje = cuentaBancaria.saldos(self)
    return mensaje

  def ingresos(self):
    ingreso = int(input("¿Cuanto quiere ingresar de dinero?: "))
    aumento2 = self.saldo + ingreso
    aumento = (f"Tu saldo es ahora de: {aumento2}")
    return aumento
  
  def retiros(self):
    retiro = int(input("Cuanto dinero quieres retirar?: "))
    if retiro > self.saldo:
      disminucion =  "Ud no cuenta con el saldo suficiente"
    else:
      disminucion2 = self.saldo - retiro
      disminucion = f"Tu saldo es ahora de: {disminucion2}"
    return disminucion
  
  def saldos(self):
    saldo_actual = self.saldo
    return saldo_actual

mi_sueldo = cuentaBancaria("Juan", 199733051214, 1000)
saldoActual = mi_sueldo.inicio()
print(saldoActual)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es mejor que la respuesta contenga toda la información necesaria. Hacer referencia a otras respuestas o comentarios dificulta la lectura. Puedes editar la respuesta para agregar esa información que mencionas.

Comment: He editado la respuesta, espero que te ayude. Un saludo.

Comment: No sabes de casualidad como hacer para registrar los movimientos que hago, el libro me dice que debo mostrar los registro bancarios, pero no se como.

Comment: ¿Dónde te piede que muestres los registros?
1. En la consola.
2. En una base de datos.
3. En un archivo de log.

Comment: En el libro me pide un registro de los retiros y ingresos, cómo si consultaras los movimiento de tu tarjeta

Comment: cuando puse else al final de def inicio, me salia none en ingreso, tuve que poner return a todos los if y else, aun no entedi porque

Comment: Si has puesto return a todos los if y else es poque los tienes dentro de dichos if y else. Observa el código que te escribí con la solución yo el "return" lo comienzo a escribir en la misma tabulación. ¿eso lo entiendes?

Comment: Te he dejado una imagen explicando un poco. De todas formas no se si lo estás intentando tú solo con un libro o te están impartiendo clases. La documentación oficial tiene todo: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

También hay un tutorial de Python sencillo aquí: 
https://www.w3schools.com/python/default.asp

Mi consejo es que entiendas bien que es una función, que hace, para que sirve, porque puede llevar return o no, etc.

Answer (score 1):

no soy experto es más soy nuevo aqui; pero he tenido el mismo dilema recientemente.
Resulta que al pedirle al programa que imprima por primera vez en la linea
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
esta ejecuta el primer print ubicado en la funcion y cuando se le vuelve a llamar fuera de esta funcion [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] no tiene dato alguno para mostrar y arroja "none".

Te recomiendo mientras te encuentres dentro de la funcion utilizar "return" y cuando estes fuera de ella puedes usar el "print" de modo practico.

Te dejo el caso que me sucedio a mi.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [answer] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu respuesta sea marcada como aceptada. También proporciona el código de lo que has hecho (en texto, no imagen) para que comiences  a ganar reputación y medallas.